# Low internal consistency

Tags: binary-data, survey, reliability, cronbachs-alpha, item-analysis

I am currently analyzing the data for a survey I have completed. In doing so, one question is quite simple (nominal) and require a typical “I do/I do not” and “I do not/I do” response from the participants. The questions have an $83.7\%$ and $75.25\%$ “yes” feedback. When I run a reliability analysis (Cronbach's alpha and split-half both show the same results) however, I get $\alpha = .46$. This seems awfully low considering the consistency of the responses. There are almost $500$ completed responses to the survey and my initial thought is that I must be doing something wrong.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "83,7% and 75,25% “yes” feedback", or maybe I do know what you mean, but I don't know what that has to do with alpha. You have two variables? Can you show us the contingency table?

Comment: @JeremyMiles   Thank you for responding to my issue. 

First question: Generally speaking, would you say that most people can be trusted or that you need to be very careful in dealing with people?

Response options and feedback from respondents: 
1. Most people can be trusted (83,7%)
2. Need to be very careful (16,3%)
Second question: Would you say you trust people easily or are you generally speaking sceptical about giving people your trust?
1. I trust people easily (72,25%)
2. I am generally speaking sceptical about giving people my trust (24,75%)

Comment: @JeremyMiles   The idea is to check internal consistency and my initial thought was that by running these numbers through a CA or  split-half I would get a far higher internal consistency than the 0,46.

Comment: Reliability (internal consistency) is a function of the number of items. More items gives you higher reliability, so with only two items, it's going to be hard. In addition, reliability increases as your split gets closer to 50%, so with 84% endorsing one of the questions, you won't get a high estimate.